# How to get a count of rows (across tables) dependent on a particular column which is referenced as a foreign key in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys

I want to delete a particular row in a table. the id column of that row is used as a foreign key by many tables. How can I get a count of such references to that particular row value of the id column across all tables?

I dont want to do a delete cascade or set null value. So, I want to know if the row to  be deleted has something depending upon it or not and if there is nothing depending on that row go ahead with the delete.

table employee has a row with id_employee = 1001, which i want to delete.

id_employee = 1001 occurs in 3 other tables which reference it using a foreign key constraint (checking manually).

How to get the count of same by a select query?

Comment: True that ... i upvote your comment, gj

Comment: There is nothing built-in. You will need to query the system tables for the dependencies and then create a SQL query to retrieve those counts using dynamic SQL .

Comment: If you just want to delete a row if there are no referencing rows, create foreign key with `on delete restrict` and do `delete`.

Comment: I am literally doing that now. I am running the delete query and letting it fail and handling the exception. Not  an elegant method and eats up a few seconds as well ... giving the impression of sluggish code. Wanted to see if I could pre-determine, and then either give the user an warning message or proceed with the delete and give him a success message. Could this be a candidate function for future releases of postgres?